# rename interface method parameter name

Tags: java, generics, interface

I defined an interface:

```
public Interface A
{
   foo(String criteria)
}
```

Can I rename the parameter name in the implementing class?

```
final public B implements A
{
   foo(String name)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can rename the variable name, it is not a part of the signature.

The signature of a method includes its return type, the method name, and the type and order of its parameters.

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can. The variable (parameter) *name* is not part of the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the parameter name is not part of the interface.